# Data fica errada ao converter para Date em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, angular

Olá, eu tenho uma API em .net que retorna os dados, a data vem no formato: `2016-06-17T00:00:00` e eu tento converte-la para data no JavaScript, então faço o seguinte:

```
 var data = new Date(2016-06-17T00:00:00);
```

Funciona, mas a data fica diferente na variável, ele sempre muda o dia.
O que eu teria que fazer para a conversão ocorrer normalmente?

Não acontece sempre, por exemplo no caso abaixo ocorre:
data da API: 2015-07-25T00:00:00

```
var data = new Date('2015-07-25T00:00:00');
```

A data fica a seguinte: Fri Jul 24 2015 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil), o dia é alterado.

Só que no próximo exemplo não ocorre:
Data da API: 2016-06-24T09:23:53
Após converter usando o mesmo código a data fica a mesma: Fri Jun 24 2016 06:23:53 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)

Comment: See this documentation helped me in the formatting issue.
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

É isso mesmo, o js considera que a string que você está passando como parâmetro esta no formato UTC (pois não tem o fuso horário na string), por isso quando converte para Date ele considera o seu fuso-horário, no caso GMT-3 por isso ele subtrai 3 horas do horário da string.

Uma forma de evitar isso seria fazer com que sua API retornasse o fuso-horário na string, algo assim: '2015-07-25T00:00:00-0300'

Comment: É importante dizer que o fuso horário NÃO é uma constante, o javascript pega o fuso horário do Browser do usuário, então o fuso horário varia de região e período do ano. Por exemplo, aqui meu fuso horário está em GMT-3 (Horário Padrão de Brasília), mas, quando entrar o horário de verão passará a ser GMT-2 (Horário de Verão de Brasília). Portanto, a solução `new Date('2015-07-25T00:00:00-0300')` irá falhar quando (ou se) o Time Zone do Browser mudar. Para solucionar, a data pode ser salva em GMT+0 no banco de dados, ou salva juntamente com seu fuso horário para usá-lo ao instanciar `Date`.